# rails - display all the elements of a class in a view that is not that class' index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a site with novels and illustrations.  On an illustration's show page, I wish to show a thumbnail grid of all the illustrations that belong to the same novel.  How can I call a method (with parameters) in the illustrations_controller from the view to return a list of novels that I get with a find method?  I've tried the following but the error message claims i don't have this message in the controller:

`<% @illustrations = IllustrationsController.get_related_by_novel %>`

Here's the method in the controller:

```
class IllustrationsController < ApplicationController
.
.#some code here
.
  def get_related_by_novel
    @illustrations = Illustration.find(params[:id][:novel])
  end
end
```

Even if I get this call to work, I don't know how to pass the params from the currently viewed illustration to the controller so it can run the query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Even if I get this call to work, I don't know how to pass the params from the currently viewed illustration to the controller so it can run the query."
You might want to read up the Rails guide about [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). A standard RESTful route to show an illustration would just be:

`get /illustrations/:id => illustrations#show`

This would send the request to the IllustrationsController with a `params[:id]` set to the Illustration id. Your controller should ideally delegate to the model to find related illustrations. Assuming you have a standard has many and belongs to relationship between Novel and Illustration, then your controller code could look like so:

```
class IllustrationsController
  def show
    @illustration = Illustration.find(params[:id])
    @related_illustrations = @illustration.find_related
  end
end
```

and your model code could look like this:

```
class Illustration
  def find_related
    self.novel.illustrations - [self]
  end
end
```

There are always more ways to do this, but to my mind this keeps the association logic with the model and keeps the controller light weight.

Comment: That's such an elegant solution.  Thanks for the description.  That really helps me understand how you can put some utility in a model and not just the controller.  That's something I've been struggling with.  Thanks!